# HTML image in a span tag align both at the bottom

Tags: html, css, angular, alignment

I have 2 images side by side, both in their  tag. The one image is smaller than the other, however, they are both "hooked" at the top of their bounding parent element (or their outer box element, not sure how to say this).

```
<span style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;  vertical-align:top"><img src="/assets/images/xxxxx.png" class="xxxxx" alt="XXXXX"  height="30px" width="auto"/></span>

<span style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;"><img src="/assets/images/xx.png" class="xx" alt="xx"  height="45px" width="auto"/></span>
```

But I would like to place the second smaller image aligned at the bottom with the other image, not at the top... currently they look like this:

[image: Both pictures aligned at the top]

However, I would like them be aligned at the bottom, so that the second smaller image is on the same level at the bottom with the bigger image

Edit:
Sorry I forgot, they are both surrounded in an additional  tag from Angular js "ngx-admin" template.. maybe that has to do something with it?

Comment: in second span use bottom:0; instead of top:0; Hope this helps

Comment: you need to provide a fiddle or codepen link replicating this issue for someone to properly help you out.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out myself...
Just had to add some manual snippet on the first one:

```
 bottom: 0; top:5px;
```

that did the trick and added some margin on top.... 
somehow margin-top or padding-top did not work either...

Answer (score 2):

Use `vertical-align:bottom"` into your second span:-

```html
<span style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;  vertical-align:top"><img src="/assets/images/xxxxx.png" class="xxxxx" alt="XXXXX"  height="30px" width="auto"/></span>

<span style="position: relative; left: 0; bottom: 0; vertical-align:bottom"><img src="/assets/images/xx.png" class="awsi-logo" alt="xx"  height="45px" width="auto"/></span>
```

Comment: I also tried that, but didn't help either..   I forgot to say they are both in another <nb-action> tag surrounded, see my edits...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
<span style="position: relative; left: 0; bottom: 0;"><img src="/assets/images/xx.png" class="awsi-logo" alt="xx"  height="45px" width="auto"/></span>
```

Comment: unfortunately, that did not help, I forgot to say they are both in another <nb-action> tag surrounded, see my edits...